# How to prevent submitting a form , if a form have multiple buttons?

Tags: angular, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form, but it contains multiple button like browse file button etc.When I click other button, form is submitting.How to prevent it ?. And give submit only in one specific button.

Environment Name
            
              
              
                This field is required
              
              
                This field requires minimum 4 characters
              
              
                You exceeded maximum limit
              
            
          
                
            KUBE Config
            
              
              
                Browse
              
              
                This field is required
              
            
            
          
           
          Clear
          
            Create

Comment: by defect all the buttons has type "submit", use `<button type="button">` in the buttons that they are not submit

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, Just add button type to other buttons.
By default every button type is submit(type='submit').
So just add other buttons to type='button'.And only give type='submit' for submit button.

eg:

```
         <button **type='button'**
                id="browse-button"
                (click)="changeReference(file_input.click())"
                mat-stroked-button
                matSuffix
              >
                Browse
           </button>
```